# How to use in SignalR method name different than actual method name in C# code?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

Consider such code on the server side -- it is dirty, but works fine:

```
public interface IBroadcastHub
{
    Task CurrentTimeAsync(DateTimeOffset time);
}

public sealed class StrongBroadcastHub : Hub<IBroadcastHub>
{
}

public sealed class StrongHubWrapper : IBroadcastHub
{
    private readonly IHubContext<StrongBroadcastHub, IBroadcastHub> _context;

    public StrongHubWrapper(IHubContext<StrongBroadcastHub, IBroadcastHub> context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public Task CurrentTimeAsync(DateTimeOffset time)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending time to");
        return _context.Clients.All.CurrentTimeAsync(time);
    }
}
```

I can create instance of the wrapper and call `CurrentTimeAsync`, all fine.

The problem -- just my personal preference -- is that I would like to call `CurrentTimeAsync` in C# code, but expose it to the world as "Hello" or whatever.

I've read [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-8.0) but I cannot manage to achieve this -- whenever I use strongly typed hub the method `SendAsync` is hidden, and when I use general hub it does not work anyway (clients seems don't receive anything). Like here:

```
public sealed class GenericBroadcastHub : Hub
{
}

public sealed class DynamicHubWrapper : IBroadcastHub
{
    private readonly IHubContext<GenericBroadcastHub> _context;

    public DynamicHubWrapper(IHubContext<GenericBroadcastHub> context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public Task CurrentTimeAsync(DateTimeOffset time)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Sending time to");
        return _context.Clients.All.SendAsync(Methods.ReceiveMessage, time);
    }
}
```

So how can I achieve this effect -- have method A in C# code, and expose it under the name B? Something like this works for ASP.Net controllers, controllers methods without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, bug in my code. Ok, I will swallow my pride :-) and leave it for educational purposes. When you are switching back and forth hubs it is essential that you don't forget to switch routing as well.

All the time I kept in the server:

```
app.MapHub<StrongBroadcastHub>(Routes.SignalR);
```

"Of course" this should be changed in sync with the hub used, so keeping my example, to:

```
app.MapHub<GenericBroadcastHub>(Routes.SignalR);
```

I only hope this is "the right way" (I mean, overall departure from strongly typed hub, to using dynamic names). As I wrote, MS explains HubMethodName attribute but I cannot figure out how to do it.